# Use ghost attribute or method for custom output in model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

If I'm creating custom output for my model should I use a method or a ghost attribute. Lets say my DB has columns first_name and last_name and I want to access them as fullName in my view. Which is better:

```
//Model
public function fullName()
{
  return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
//View
{{ $model->fullName() }}
```

Or

```
//Model
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
  return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
//View
{{ $model->fullName }}
```

Comment: first one is better I think

Comment: Use an accessor, the second one.

Comment: Absoultely second one. This type of use-cases are exactly the reason accessors were implemented.

Comment: I'd tend to favour all methods that return state beginning with get... (unless they're part of a fluent interface).  In this particular case I'd say getFullName() is fine though, you don't need to make your method names overlong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subjective questions usually have subject answers - this question is an exception.

You should almost definitely use the attribute version so you can easily take advantage of eloquent serialisation.

Laravel has attributes of the form `get[name]Attribute` front of mind for Eloquent models - and has been around since the early versions of Laravel. Meaning its concept is ingrained in the way Laravel works as a whole.

An example of serialisation for your example would be:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['full_name'];

    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
    }
}
```

Later on, that `full name` attribute will auto-magically be available in every form that this model exists - whether it's in it's Elqouent form, or if has been converted to an array (with toArray) or to a json (via toJSON).

This is brilliant because from "the outside" other parts of your application need not know if full_name is in the db table or if it's a derived attribute, its just another attribute available to be accessed and used.